# Handle returned object in Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, runtime, method-invocation

I have a Java Reflection for:

Oracle SQL class `ArrayDescriptor` and a method `createDescriptor(String, Connection)` which I use to create an Array Descriptor object in my code.

This method returns `ArrayDescriptor` object. Since, all of this is happening at the run-time. I don't know how do I handle the return value which of type `ArrayDescriptor`(same as what I'm loading at runtime).

One possibility may be:
I can collect it as an Object type. But, when I need to use this object, how do I perform the cast on this object?

I don't know, if the above is an ideal way to do this. Kindly advise on an elegant way to do this, if any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some code describing your problem in greater detail, or create an example which closely resembles it if you can't post code. You will get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your is as :
Create or replace procedure procedure_name(field1 number_t,
                                              field2 varchar2_t,
                                              o_errors       out integer_t)
is
...

The Java code should be as:
ArrayDescriptor oracleVarchar2Collection =
    ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("VARCHAR2_T",conn);

ArrayDescriptor oracleIntegerCollection =
    ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("INTEGER_T",conn);

ArrayDescriptor oracleNumberCollection =
  ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("NUMBER_T",conn);